# When did Nixon go from having his huge robotic body, to Agnew?

Tags: futurama

In the episode a head in the polls Nixon is pictured in the end with a huge robot body which he then goes crashing into the white house with. At which point did he decide to switch an awesome body for a headless moaning guy in a suit?

Answer (score 8):

Nixon doesn't ever appear again with the huge robot body, and it isn't mentioned what happened to it.

The most likely explanation: Nixon is cheap and he just *rented* the body to win the election. His cheapness is supported by the fact that he bought his first robot body (i.e. Bender's body) at a *pawn shop* and by [this dialogue from the episode](http://theinfosphere.org/Transcript%3aA_Head_in_the_Polls):

> *[Scene: Outside Watergate Hotel.]*
>
> **Fry:** [whispering] Why would Nixon stay at the Watergate?
>
> **Leela:** [whispering] They give you a discount if you've been here before.

A penny-pincher wouldn't invest more than he absolutely had to to win.

Answer (score -1):

He could not fit in the oval office if he still had the body. Compared to a normal human (his campaign manager who he stepped on), the robot body looked like the size of a three story office building. It could also alienate his voters to be taller than them so he got rid of it.

Comment: He didn't have to fit in the oval office. He simply knocked the wall down. Also, far from *alienating* his voters, the robot body helped him win the *robot* vote, which put him over the top.

Comment: This is true. Maybe Headless Agnew was to bring up the human vote.